# Nested SQL - faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I have a SQL snippet which is taking ages to run, because it is nested.. I was just wondering, whether there is a way of simplifying it so that it runs faster.

Here is the SQL:

```
select nid 
from table_A 
where bid in (select bid
              from Table_B
              where xid in (select xid 
                            from Table_C 
                            where name_l in (select name_l
                                             from accs 
                                             where prod like '%arlehen%')))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create proper indexes.

Comment: Look at the EXPLAIN PLAN for the query and determine which part(s) are slow

Comment: This is not related to nesting because I presume that Oracle does semi join of all four tables (where *semi* stands for join which returns the first matched row of the main table), which is somewhat equal to plain `join`. The issue is in the wrong estimates, so please add actual execution plan with estimated row counts and actual row counts per `join`

Comment: There is no "faster" way to write SQL one way vs. another considered by itself. What's fastest all depends on your data distribution, cardinalities, and Oracle's generated execution plans based on the statistics it has. You have to look at the plan, determine where it is spending it's time, and then come up with a way to improve it. If there was always a way to rewrite SQL so that it was always faster, Oracle would do it for you every time. But there's not.

Comment: Having said that, if this predicate: `prod like '%arlehen%'` is fairly unique then you will want to index table_c.name_l, table_b,xid and table_a.bid. But if it's fairly common, then it should be hash joining everything and then you don't want indexes. Also, if accs is very large, you may be spending most of your time on the full scan of that table, which cannot use an index because of your LIKE '%... predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query could be written like:

```
select nid 
from table_A 
where bid in (
  select b.bid
  from Table_B b
  join Table_C c on b.xid=c.xid
  join accs on c.name_l=accs.name_l
  where accs.prod like '%arlehen%');
```

Fresh statistics, meaning not stale statistics, may possibly help the optimizer choose the best execution path.

Or, another way to rewrite the query would be the below:

```
with tba as (
select a.*
from accs accs
where a.prod like '%arlehen%'
)
select nid 
from table_A 
where bid in (
  select b.bid
  from Table_B b
  join Table_C c on b.xid=c.xid
  join tba on c.name_l=tba.name_l)
;
```

Comment: But it doesn't answer why it should improve query performance, which may lead to XY problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/PbzO3WIl

Comment: Well, query performance may improve or may not. Sometimes the optimizer may not choose the best execution plan even when the statistics are not stale or you may oftentimes have that query run when statistics are stale, in which case writing the query in a different way or using hints may help. If it is better for performance, that may be seen by running each of the queries.

Comment: Nevertheless the basis for optimization is a query plan. Oracle's optimizer has very complicated capabilities of query transformations (especially when `table_x` is a view actually), so I generally resort for manual rewrite of such (somewhat simple) query only with manually added hints (for join order, access paths) to prevent inadequate reordering of tables

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try by replacing IN() by EXISTS(), that may reduce the I/O cost - to be checked on your data set, of course:

```
select nid 
from table_A a
where exists (
    select 1
    from Table_B b
    where b.bid = a.bid 
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from Table_C c
        where b.xid = c.xid
        and exists (
            select 1
             from accs ac
             where ac.prod like '%arlehen%'
             and ac.name_l = c.name_l
        )
    )
)
;
```